# Android Studio Asynchronous method error

Tags: java, android, http, android-asynctask

I'm trying to make a GET request in Android Studio and I don't understand why this method works in Eclipse as a Java program but not in Android Studio, so I supposed it was something related to threats, so I made a call to an Async Task. 
My code looks like this:

**Called method:**

```
private static class GetFarmaciasTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String[][]>{
    protected String[][] doInBackground(String... urls) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://mikelmoli.000webhostapp.com/PHP/json.php");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
            rd.close();
            JSONObject jsonO = new JSONObject(result.toString());
            //JSONObject myResponse = jsonO.getJSONObject("data");
            JSONArray tsmResponse = (JSONArray) jsonO.get("data");
            String[] indices = {"Nombre", "Provincia", "Poblacion", "Calle", "Numero", "Telefono"};
            String[][] datos = new String[tsmResponse.length()][indices.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < tsmResponse.length(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < indices.length; j++) {
                    datos[i][j] = tsmResponse.getJSONObject(i).getString(indices[j]);
                }
            }
            return datos;
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException ej) {
            ej.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The error is in this line of the code:

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

As I said before, this method works in Eclipse as an independent method.

Some of the errors which made me think about thread errors:

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: As a side note, if your GET request is REST, have a look at using the retrofit library as it handles background network requests and JSON parsing to your models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly likely because if the way you are using the `AsyncTask`. If you are seeing that exception, you are probably calling `doInBackground()` directly. This article explains how `AsyncTask` works and should help: http://hiqes.com/androids-asynctask-explained/

Also, they are one time execute objects, so I would recommend not making it `static`. There are also other subtle pitfalls with making it an inner class of something like an `Activity`, which can cause memory leaks, so be careful.

Comment: I've read the article and it has been very usefull, thanks. Despite this, I'm having trouble with the returned data I need. I call the execute() metod of the class which extends AsyncTask but, how do I get the returned values from the method doInBackground()? May I do it calling onPostExecute?

Comment: You return the data (object) at the end of `doInBackground()`.  The `onPostExecute()` method will automatically be called and provide you with the data returned by your `doInBackground()`.  You do not call any of the callbacks directly.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now